# From lite and full, Full version for OLD/Current users of APP without In app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

In my current app which is on app store..

I have added feature of lite and full version.

The user who purchase lite version they can get full version by in app purchase.

**PROBLEM**

But my problem is that for all the current user of application should get full version without make any IAP payment.

can we do this ? Is it possible to do ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if the features of the App gets unlocked by any server dependent event. If your app unlock features by registering on server or getting any particular event from there, than it is possible.

If you have to change the code, then it can't be possible without pushing the update to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

**When the IAP is cleared for sale, You are locked out from making any changes to the in-app purchase except for changes to pricing and availability.**

So make the price to Tier 1(`no free pricing for IAP`) for limited time, notify the existing users via push notification/ your website..

or,

***Make the full version available for FREE.***